# EF6 Condition based on sub child

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have this C# code that works, but I'd like to be able to choose the Agency if a person is in it all in the query. Is there a way to do that all in the query?

```
        var retVal = new List<Agency>();
        var items=_db.Agencies
               .Include(x => x.AgencyMembers.Select(y => y.Person))
               .Where(w => w.NationId == User.NationId).ToList();

        foreach (var agency in items)
        {
            if(agency.AgencyMembers.Any(c=>c.Person.Id==personId))
                retVal.Add(agency);
        }
        return retVal;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just add that predicate to your query.

```
     return _db.Agencies
        .Include(x => x.AgencyMembers.Select(y => y.Person))
        .Where(w => w.NationId == User.NationId)
        .Where(agency => agency.AgencyMembers.Any(c=>c.Person.Id==personId))
        .ToList();
```

Depending what navigation properties you have, you may be able to simplify it by starting from the person.

```
    return _db.People
        .Single(p => p.Id == personId)
        .Agencies
        .Where(w => w.NationId == User.NationId)
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
 var items=_db.Agencies
              .Include(x => x.AgencyMembers.Select(y => y.Person))
              .Where(agency=> agency.NationId == User.NationId && agency.AgencyMembers.Any(c=>c.Person.Id==personId))
              .ToList();
```